# Returning different response after Custom Filter in Mule Flow

Tags: mule

This would seem like a pretty common thing to do, but I am having trouble figuring out how to make it work. I wrote a custom filter for a request-response flow that has an inbound http endpoint. The custom filter checks if certain required query parameters are present and contain valid values. If the filter rejects a message, I would like to return an HTTP error status code, but I cannot figure out how to send a different response.

The Mule docs say:

> If the inbound endpoint defined on a Flow has a request-response
>   exchange-pattern and there are no response blocks in your flow then
>   the response used is simply the result from the last Message Processor
>   in the flow, which will be null.

I am not sure if this is entirely accurate. My flow does have a `<response>` block, but it is not getting called if my custom filter returns false.

What is the best way to return a different response if the filter rejects a message?

Here is an example of my flow:

```
<flow name="Incoming_requests">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="incoming" />

    <http:body-to-parameter-map-transformer />

    <custom-filter class="com.mycompany.MyQueryParamFilter"/>

    <!--  Process valid messages here -->

    <response>
       <!--  Return a successful response  -->
    </response>
</flow>
```

EDIT:  Here is are the docs that inferred that `<response>` blocks would be executed. 
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Using+Filters#UsingFilters-UsinginFlows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a [choice router](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-Choice) would be better in your case:

```
<choice>
  <when expression="...validation expression...">
    <!--  Process valid messages here -->
    <!--  Return a successful response  -->
  </when>
  <otherwise>
    <!--  Return a failure response  -->
  </otherwise>
</choice>
```

No `response` elements are necessary if the `choice` is at the end of the `flow`.

Comment: I was originally going down this path, but it didn't seem like the cleanest design to me. I have a number of flows like this I didn't like the idea of nesting all these conditionals everywhere. I simple custom filter seemed so much more attractive.

Comment: I think the doc is unclear: the buck stops at the filter so I believe the response element must be *before* the filter. Regarding `choice`, I don't know how you'll be able to return different responses (successful or failure) with only filters...